# How to prove $r(x)>p(x)$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, derivatives

Given two functions $r(x)$ and $p(x)$, both of which are defined on closed interval $x\in[a,b]$.

Functions $r(x)$ and $p(x)$ also satisfy the following constraints:
\begin{cases}
r(a)=p(a)\\
r'(x)>p'(x)
\end{cases}

Then how to prove $r(x)>p(x)$ on a left open and right closed interval $(a,b]$?

Comment: Thank you for informing me. I have corrected it.

Comment: Hint: Look at $r(x)-p(x)$ and its derivative.

Comment: @Vim I wasn't thinking about FCT or integrals at all. MVT is enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $h(x)=r(x)-p(x)$, then $h'(x)>0$ so $h$ is strictly increasing. As $h(a)=0$, we have $h(x)>0$ for $x>a$.

Comment: By far the best one.

Answer (score 2):

Simple Integration with $a>x\geq b$

$$r(x)=r(a)+\int_a^x r'(x) dx>p(a)+\int_a^x p'(x)dx=p(x)$$

Comment: I don't think you can directly apply FTC here. No regularity condition is imposed on the derivatives indeed.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a completely elementary axiomatic method without integration:

You have by definition of derivative

$$\lim_{x\to a+}\frac{r(x)-r(a)}{x-a} = r'(a) > p'(a) = \lim_{x\to a+}\frac{p(x)-p(a)}{x-a}$$

so you may choose an $\varepsilon > 0$ such that for all $x \in (a, a+\varepsilon)$ you have

$$\frac{r(x)-r(a)}{x-a}> \frac{p(x)-p(a)}{x-a}.$$

Since $x-a > 0$ and $r(a) = p(a)$, we get $r(x) > p(x)$ for all $x \in (a, a+\varepsilon)$, now choose $b := a+\varepsilon/2$ and you're done.

Comment: Could you tell me the meaning of the last sentence ``now choose $b:=a+\varepsilon/2$ and you are done''.

Comment: I noticed I had an unnecessary sentence in my solution, I removed that. If you choose $b = a + \varepsilon/2$, you get $r(x) > p(x)$ for all $x \in (a, b] \subset (a, a+\varepsilon)$.

Comment: But $b$ is a pre-defined constant, not a variable that can be choosed. So perhaps your proof is not perfect. Am I right?

Comment: Oh, I see. Whoops. In that case my proof is not enough, it only shows $h(x) := r(x)-p(x)$ is strictly increasing locally around $a$. In that case, Surb's proof is the idea you want. If you still need to prove that functions with positive derivative are strictly increasing (which I doubt considering the nature of your question), you can easily modify my proof to show that $h$ is locally strictly increasing in any point (not just at $a$), then use this fact to show that $h$ is *globally* strictly increasing, using the local case appropriately.

Comment: Not enough though, your idea is ingenious.